# Is it possible that w3wp.exe deleted my files?

Tags: c#, iis, w3wp.exe

A strange situation occours on my Windows 2012 server...

I have a MVC application on IIS, sometimes many files are deleted.

To understand what append I configured an audit policy in this app folder (E:\Siti\schoolsmanager.it)

this is the audit log, for one of the many deleted files :

Soggetto:
 ID sicurezza: SYSTEM
 Nome account: SRV2012$
 Dominio account: ALCE
 ID accesso: 0x3E7

Oggetto:
 Server dell'oggetto: Security
 Tipo di oggetto: File
 Nome oggetto: E:\Siti\schoolsmanager.it\Web.config
 ID handle: 0xd40
 Attributi risorsa: S:AI

Informazioni sul processo:
 ID processo: 0x1210
 Nome processo: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Informazioni di richiesta di accesso:
 Accessi: DELETE

Maschera di accesso: 0x10000"
Informazioni 18/11/2015 13.39.02 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 4660 File system "Un oggetto è stato eliminato.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: are you able to translate your message in English please? also w3wp wont delete files... only by an external process but not by IIS

Comment: If you have code running under IIS that interacts with the file system then w3wp will be the process thats audited as doing such.

Comment: w3wp.exe is hosting web applications for you and if the apps decide to delete anything you see in file audit that w3wp.exe does deletion. So you will have to dive deeper into it via further debugging.

Comment: Subject:  
 Security ID : SYSTEM  
 Account Name: SRV2012$  
 Account Domain: ALCE  
 Logon ID: 0x3E7  

Object:  
 Object Server: Security  
 Object Type: File  
 Object Name: E:\Siti\schoolsmanager.it\Web.config  
 Handle ID: 0xd40  
 Object Attibutes: S:AI  
  
Process Information:  
 Process ID: 0x1210  
 Process Name: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe  
  
Access request informations:  
 Access: DELETE   
 Access Mask: 0x10000"  
Informations 18/11/2015 13.39.02 Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing 4660 File system "An object is been deleted.

Comment: **In any IIS apps there aren't delete function**, is it possible is a virus ?